# CQL3: Select where TTL = 0

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cqlsh

I have terabytes of data in my cassandra nodes that have a TTL of zero.  I want to start deleting this data if I can.

I'm trying to get a list of this data.  I want a command similar to:

```
SELECT TTL (value) FROM data_points WHERE TTL (value) = 0
```

I can't seem to get anything of that sort to work.  Extensive searching reveals that no one seems to have tried to do this before, which I suspect means it can't be done.  Still, I'd be interested to see if there are ways of gathering this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to select data with a specific TTL.

[This link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_expire_c.html) may help you to understand how expired data management in cassandra works.

Comment: Thanks.  This is as I expected, but I dared to hope.